# AWK date to epoch

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I have the following command that returns a date from a file

```
tail -1 MyFile | awk -F ',' '{print $7}'
```

Returns date like this `04/16/12 20:44:19`

I want to convert that date to epoch time by modifying the awk command somehow by feeding $7 into `date -d $7 +%s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `awk` is a bit heavy for this job, `cut` maybe a little bit lighter:

```
tail -1 MyFile | date -d "`cut -d, -f7`" +%s
```

But of course you can do it with `awk` as well:

```
tail -1 MyFile | date -d "`awk -F, '{ print $7 }'`" +%s
```

Comment: Have used cut now although I did get it working with awk aswell. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

*GNU awk* has *builtin* time functions:

```
tail -1 infile | awk -F, '{
  split($7, t, /[/: ]+/)
  t[3] = t[3] > 69 ? 19 t[3] : 20 t[3]
  print mktime(t[3]" "t[1]" "t[2]" "t[4]" "t[5]" "t[6]) 
  }'
```