# Awk ISO to epoch

Tags: time, awk, iso, epoch

I am writing a script in bash using `awk` (mawk) and I would like to return the output of a system command to awk.

I have a variable called `created` that is in ISO format: `2013-12-26T17:03:05Z` and I want to convert it from ISO to epoch.  I can run this line `created_epoch=system("date +\%s -d " created)` and it prints the output to the terminal, but the variable `created_epoch` is equal to `0`, not the epoch time.

Does anyone know how I can convert an ISO format to epoch in awk?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [AWK date to epoch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180609/awk-date-to-epoch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `getline` into a variable from a pipe instead of `system`

```
cmd="date +\%s -d "created; cmd | getline current_time
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fVariable_002fPipe.html#Getline_002fVariable_002fPipe

The `system` command returns the exit status returned by the command that was executed as its value.
http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gawk/gawk_137.html

Comment: is this the best we can do? if my input is too large and it runs that on every line, it always fails with "Too many open files". Is there a filehandle I can close() ?

Comment: I guess I figured it out... just need a `close(cmd)` ... on the command string used as if it's a file handle

Answer (score 1):

The `system` command in awk, as in C, returns the exit status of a command, and *not* the output of said command.  As others have suggested, your best bet is using [`getline` from a pipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fPipe.html#Getline_002fPipe)

I ran into a similar problem a while back and rolled my own `exec` function, here it is:

```
# get the output of a command
function exec(cmd,      data) {
  while ((cmd | getline data) > 0) printf("%s", data);
  close(cmd);
}
```

Then using the function defined above, you should do something like this:

```
epoch = exec("date +%s -d \"<ISO DATE>\"")
```

where `<ISO DATE>` is an ISO conformant date/timestamp.

Example:

```
# helper.awk is where `exec` is defined
awk '@include "helper.awk"; BEGIN
{ 
  epoch = exec("gdate -d \"2014-02-14T12:30\" +%s");
  print epoch
}'
# 1392406200
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation and for the multi-line solution (though @Håkon Hægland's single-line solution will do in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
created_epoch=$(date +\%s -d "$created")
echo $created_epoch
1388077385
```

Comment: I think that is how to do it in a shell script, but that will not work in an AWK script inside of a shell script.